# Xamarin Forms Open URI with access token

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, adal

I have POC Xamarin Forms PCL app and authenticated successfully with MSAL. My REST calls(to read user profile and sharepoint list data) to graph API are all successful.

I am trying to open a sharepoint page in the browser using the token, i.e. without asking the users the re-authenticate.

Device.openUri always sends the users to an auth page, which makes sense since i am not sending the token with it.

Is this possible at all? If so, How can it be done?

Comment: You've received the token for web api call and by using web-view, you're launching a page. These are two separate 'resources', in this case SharePoint will ask you to re-authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to exactly what you're asking is "no", and to what you are looking to achieve is "probably not". At least not today with MSAL directly.

When the user is sent off to sign in, MSAL is invoking a platform-dependent browser window which navigates to Azure AD for the sign-in and consent process. Depending on the device platform, this browser window may (or may not) share a cookie state with other apps and the full browser.

If it *does* share the cookie space, then the cookies set during the sign-in to your app can be re-used when you launch SharePoint in the browser, to provide a relatively seamless sign-in straight to SharePoint. If it does *not*, then there will be no existing browser session artifacts (i.e. cookies) that Azure AD can use to provide single sign-in.

For example, on iOS (Xamarin), MSAL for .NET will invoke SFSafariViewController. SFSafariViewController does *not* share cookie space with other apps or with the Safari browser.

Comment: I was also looking for this and have just read Philippes answer. As a workaround I am thinking to pass the "token/identifier" as URL/REST-Parameter; like "https://example.com/FECAD0". Another side-effekt: the normal token-handling (for login, etc.) will not be affected.